# SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 10, tokens 0.0.0, 10.5.4, Process Owner: IIS APPPOOL\webapi

Tags: asp.net, db2, iis-8, db2-luw

I am using IBM DB2 for LUW v10.5. webapi (ASP.NET application) is the name of the application hosted on IIS. Encountered below error when calling webapi methods.

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>The underlying provider failed on Open.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Data.EntityException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() at WriteArrayOfPCMUSERToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 10, tokens 0.0.0, 10.5.4, Process Owner: IIS APPPOOL\webapi
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.Open(DB2Connection connection, String& szConnectionString, DB2ConnSettings& ppSettings, Object& ppConn) at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.Open() at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Comment: Please add more info into your question. Code snippets or stack trace are useful in troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: Updated the question with error log

Answer (score 0):

Detail explanation of SQL1159N can be found at below URL:

**SQL1159N An error occurred during initialization of the IBM Data Server Provider for .NET. Reason Code: reason-code.**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic5.html#sql1159n

Here is snip of **Explanation**:

You can access the IBM database system with the IBM Data Server Provider for .Net.

This message is returned when there is a problem with the database product installation. This message can also be returned when the Windows extended security feature is enabled and the ID that is used to start the Internet Information Systems (IIS) service does not belong to the DB2ADMNS group or to the DB2USERS group.

The reason code for this message is intended for IBM support personnel only.

Hope this helps.